# How to check if an array is equal to some set of values

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, compiler-errors

I know this seems a little odd to ask such a question but it's annoying me!

```
char winnerCheck[5];
if (winnerCheck=={'X','X','X','X','X'})
{
    cout<<second<<", you won the game!"; 
}
```

it gives me (`[Error] expected primary-expression before '{' token`) for the second line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays and this will do what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Go away from the legacy C arrays. Use `std::array` and it's simple:

```
std::array<char, 5> winnerCheck;;
if (winnerCheck == std::array{'X','X','X','X','X'})
{

}
```

If you don't have C++17 yet you just need to add the `std::array` template arguments:

```
std::array<char, 5> winnerCheck;;
if (winnerCheck == std::array<char, 5>{'X','X','X','X','X'})
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the std::string as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char winnerCheck[2];
    winnerCheck[0] = 'X';
    winnerCheck[1] = 'X';
    if(std::string(winnerCheck) == std::string({'X','X'}))
    {
        cout<<"you won the game"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most straight forward way should be:

```
if (winnerCheck[0] == 'A' && winnerCheck[1] == 'B' ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare the content of C arrays like that. There isn't any syntax do so.

I propose you use a function to check for a winner. Here is an example, it will blow up if you give pass the function a null pointer but it stops as soon the two strings are different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool isWinner(char *playerStr)
{
  static const char winningStr[5] = { 'X','X', 'X', 'X', 'X' };

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      if (playerStr[i] != winningStr[i])
        {
          return false;
        }
    }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << isWinner("abdce") << std::endl;
  std::cout << isWinner("XYZXX") << std::endl;
  std::cout << isWinner("XXXXZ") << std::endl;
  std::cout << isWinner("XXXXX") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether all characters are same or not like your example, you can also use `std::all_of` as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rTzrZqrVZwG2EHqi)

```
if (std::all_of(std::begin(winnerCheck), std::end(winnerCheck),
                [](char x) { return (x == 'X'); }))
{
    std::cout << "You won the game!"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite what several answers have suggested, don’t create a temporary container (`std::vector` or `std::string`) from your `winnerCheck` array. Constructing and destroying those containers adds a lot of thrashing. Instead, use an algorithm:

```
static const char winner[5] = { `X`, `X`, `X`, `X`, `X` };
char winnerCheck[5] = whatever;
if (std::equal(std::begin(winner), std::end(winner), winnerCheck))
    std::cout << “You won the game\n”;
```